# Create a search box for an HTML page in a .war file

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have web project which included JSP pages in HTML pages. It's basically a product ordering website. When I run its `.war` file on my local machine, it has a search box on every page where you can search locally on the website. I cant get the search box to work for my `.war`. I've looked up for the code to do so on the web, and it says to enter the website's URL in the search value but I don't have a URL its basically a project!
The URL I'm using to run the project is [http://localhost:8080/myProjectWar/].

Comment: Your question makes little sense and seems to have nothing to do with the fact that you're using a WAR file for packaging.  If you're looking to use an external service then the service needs to be able to actually access the proper data.  You need to provide more information and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Doesn't sounds like a question that a Java "Pro" would ask.

Answer (score 0):

You want apply search on your own application. Very easy and suitable solution is just apply google custom search on your application.

Convert your search box to google custom search box. Entire searching and displaying the results and links will be take care by google.

Register your application with google custom search engine and get your credentials.
Try below link for registering .
[Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/)